# GridGain remote cache size always zero

Tags: gridgain

I have a configuration where cache is kept in one node and accessed from another. Although I am able to get() and put() perfectly fine, some operations like size(), keySet() etc don't return me correct results.

Test1 Client node cache config

```
<bean id="test-cache" class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration">
    <property name="name" value="testCache"/>
     <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
    <property name="distributionMode" value="CLIENT_ONLY" />
    <property name="swapEnabled" value="true"/>

</bean>
```

Test1 Client Node Class

```
public class GridGainTest1
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        //Client Mode
        Grid g = GridGain.start("etc/config/grid-test1.xml");
        //Put in Remote Cache
        g.cache("testCache").put(1, "ABC");
        g.cache("testCache").put(2, "XYZ");

        System.out.println("Size of Cache :- " + g.cache("testCache").size());
        System.out.println("Value for 1 :- " + g.cache("testCache").get(1));
        System.out.println("Value for 2 :- " + g.cache("testCache").get(2));
    }
```

Test2 data node cache config

```
 <bean id="test-cache" class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration">
    <property name="name" value="testCache"/>
     <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
    <property name="swapEnabled" value="true"/>

</bean>
```

Test2 Data Node Class

```
    public class GridGainTest2
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Grid g = GridGain.start("etc/config/grid-test2.xml");
    }
}
```

The output from Node 1 is as follows where size comes in as 0 even though there are entries in the map. I am not sure if this is due to some misconfiguration.

```
Size of Cache :- 0
Value for 1 :- ABC
Value for 2 :- XYZ
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GridGain cache API methods `size()`, `primarySize()`, `nearSize()`, `keySet()`, `primaryKeySet()`, `values()`, `primaryValues()`, `entrySet()`, `primaryEntrySet()` are local, they will return sizes or collections only for keys stored on the local node.

In your case you started the cache on Test1 in `CLIENT_ONLY` mode, so that node does not store any keys. That is the reason why you always see `0` as cache size.

If you need global cache size, you can use the following code:

```
    GridCallable<Integer> sizeCallable = new GridCallable<Integer>() {
        @Override public Integer call() throws Exception {
            return g.cache("testCache").size();
        }
    };

    Collection<Integer> sizes = g.forCache("testCache").compute()
        .broadcast(sizeCallable).get();

    int globalSize = 0;

    for (Integer s : sizes)
        globalSize += s;
```

Convenience `GridCache.globalSize()` method will be added in the upcoming GridGain 6.2 release.

Comment: your solution works. However when I try to get size on a local off heap cache (cacheMode=LOCAL, and memoryMode=OFFHEAP_TIERED), i get the same issue where I get the value but no size. Even the above code does not work. Any ideas ?

Comment: `size()` method returns number of on-heap entries. When `OFFHEAP_TIERED` memory mode is used, cache entries are stored off-heap right away. To get number of off-heap entries in cache, use `GridCache.offheapEntriesCount()`